# Crontab issues with job editing in Vim text

Tags: vim, cron

When I try to modify jobs for the user using cronotab via text editor (vim), I cannot use the command `*/2` because there is a no string under cursor error, but I don't want to insert anything into the text file itself. So how can I use the `*` symbol as just a character in a command rather than using it as its own command.

Comment: What exactly do you expect `*/2` to do?

Comment: Can you please post exact sequence of keystrokes since the time you execute `crontab -e` command?

Answer (score 1):

Vim is a modal editor, which means that it has modes dedicated to different kinds of tasks. One consequence of this is that pressing a given key in one mode is going to do something different than pressing the same key in another mode.

When you start Vim, you are in *normal* mode, which is dedicated to moving around, copying, deleting, etc. In that mode, `*` jumps to the next occurrence of the word under the cursor and yells at you if there is nothing to search for under the cursor.

Does the behaviour described above make sense to you? Is that what you want? If not, what do you expect `*/2` to do and what is your goal?